# Will adding a pole in the loop gain make the system more unstable?

Tags: operational-amplifier, feedback, constant-current, stability

[image: Current Controller]

In the design above, the circuit designer added a low-pass filter in the feedback path of the op-amp for loop stability.

Won't adding a pole to the feedback factor actually make the circuit more unstable?

Source: https://www.radiolocman.com/shem/schematics.html?di=278861

Comment: I think there should be a gate resistor to isolate the gate from the op-amp output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about C1: It will improve stability. Judging from the freqencies that are supplied to the opamp non-ionverting input with the intent of modulating the diode current, the components C1 + R4 are a lowpass. It will limit the maximum frequency the diode can be modulated with.

But for any signal that comes from the opamp output and travels to its inverting input (i.e. the feedback path), the same components are actually a highpass.

If it were missing, the feedback would be very inefficient at high frequencies: The source of Q1 will react with a tiny delay to voltages applied to its gate. This can make the opamp oscillate. If you add a small C1, you damp this oscillation by bypassing the feedback circuit at high frequencies and forming a simple voltage follower at high frequencies. R4 is then placed to decouple the source of Q1 and inverting input at high frequencies but maintain the low frequency feedback connection. The R4 + C1 also define the corner frequency of the filter.

You can obtain the same corner frequency for different RC combination with the same RC product. The tradeoff is between opamp current and noise. Small C and high R (as done in your circuit) will allow not so much high frequency current but will create around 10 nV/rtHz of noise in the feedback path. So for it would be not a good choice if noise performance is paramount. Larger C and smaller R will reduce noise, but increase the output current of the opamp at high frequencies.

Answer (score 1):

> Won't adding a pole to the feedback factor actually make the circuit
> more unstable?

Actually no, right the opposite - without it it would be unstable.

Each closed loop in real world has a certain delay, that implies that there exist a such  frequency that would produce a phase shift of 180 degrees. If the amplification is large enough then it becomes to oscillate. With a lowpass filter you damp those high frequencies in order to be able to maintain a high gain.  Higher the gain, means better control accuracy (P controller as used in this example) and high dynamics.

Without a lowpass filter, you would have to lower the gain, thus making it less responsive and high regulation error.